# Can't print from some hosts on the network

Tags: windows, networking, printing, network-printer, wifi

I have  a HP Color LaserJet CM6040 connected on a network, and have many hosts (laptops) connected wirelessly to it, but some of the hosts can't print on this printer.
I've restarted the printer and re-installed de printer on this hosts but the problem continues and i'm out of ideas.

Comment: Can you ping the printer from those computers?

Comment: Yes i can ping the printer from the hosts and it doesn't give any connection errors

Answer (score 0):

Check that all the other devices are using the right drivers and the same version? Also leave the printer queue window opened. See if it goes into the queue and disappear after you press print.

Comment: Tryied that and didn't solve, switched the printer off and on again and started working and then the problem started again maybe  the printer was overloaded. Sometimes works fine and then the problem returns